# getElementsByTagName and childnodes

Tags: javascript, xml, getelementsbytagname

i have the xml response below and i need to get the Key value, without success.
Tried many variations but it returns no value

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <AuthenticateResponse xmlns="http://domain.something/JobServicesV2.asmx">
            <AuthenticateResult>
                <Result>0</Result>
                <Key>fxcCiBSs2fsdfsDF$=</Key>
            </AuthenticateResult>
        </AuthenticateResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

My Javascript code is this:

```
function Auth() { 
                var vAnswer ={};
                var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                var vDomain = "http://domain.something/JobServicesV2.asmx/"
                var vAuth = "Authenticate?sUsrName=xxxxx&sUsrPwd=zzzzzzz"
                var vURL = vDomain.concat(vAuth);
                var data = {};
                var xhr = Getxhr();
                xhr.open("GET", vURL, false); 
                xhr.send(data); 
                var resp = xhr.responseText;
                try {
                xmlDoc.async = false;
                xmlDoc.loadXML(resp);
                var vData = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Key")[0].childNodes;
                return vData;                       
                 }
                catch(e) {
                    X.WARNING("Error Message: " + e.message);
                }
```

vData is always empty

Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Eddiee

Comment: Avoid using synchronous requests. It will halt the thread and prevents the browser of executing any JavaScript while your request is loading. Do you need to support legacy browsers?

Answer (score 2):

This is available in only IE. If you use Chrome or Firefox, you can use DOMParser.

```
var parser = new DOMParser();  
doc = parser.parseFromString(resp, 'text/xml');
var vData  = doc.getElementsByTagName("Key")[0].childNodes;
```